# Ubuntu 8.04 (hardy): No network devices (Asus laptop)

Tags: networking, laptop, 8.04

Just installed 8.04 alongside win7 on my trusty Asus laptop to run as a local server in my studio. 
But just going into desktop after install, there are no network devices available. I check *System Administration Network* and the only object inside *Connections* is "Point to point connection".

And I'm really not sure what else to do at this point, this is completely new to me and I was following a guide that used 8.04 as an example, which mentions nothing of this unfortunately.

EDIT: I checked inside "Hardware Drivers" and found that no proprietary drivers are in use. 
Also, pressing "Enable Networking" does nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t mean 18.04? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu releases are yy.mm in format, hence 8.04 LTS means 2008.April release date. LTS releases come with 5 years (only 3 in 2008), and normal releases come with 9 months of free support.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 8.04 is over 10 years old and went out of service in 2011 for desktops.

If your laptop is more recent it could be using new hardware that is not recognized. Try with a [recent and supported Ubuntu version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Version_timeline).

A guide that uses 8.04 must be fairly outdated.